# What size should my tab bar item icons be?

Tags: ios, uitabbarcontroller, uitabbar

[This document](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/MobileHIG/IconMatrix.html) from Apple states multiple sizes for the tab bar items depending on the device. How do I specify multiple images?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is only one size being specified in that document for tab bar items - 25x25. The other two are simply 2x and 3x variants - not per device but per screen resolution. Thus the way to do this is the same way we've always done it for images in general. Use the asset catalog or use the `@2x` and `@3x` name suffixes. (I prefer the asset catalog; it doesn't get any easier.)